# Eliminating feedback in Java Sound?

Tags: java, audio, feedback-loop

I have completed a Java program that is for video-conferencing. It reads and writes from the mic/speaker of a network camera that includes two-way audio. This network camera does not have feedback reduction built in, so I must do it myself.

I can manually measure the latency, and use volume adjustment to cut out the mic to eliminate the feedback in that way, but do you have a better idea?

Ideally, my program would eliminate the feedback, without having to cut out unwanted parts. Suppose I am in a two-way conversation. I don't want to miss what the other side is saying, simply because I am talking at the same moment, especially because there is significant latency.

Can you recommend a library, or at least a strategy, for eliminating feedback?

Additionally, I would like any tips you may have on eliminating the fuzz that occurs even if the room is completely quiet. Again, I can use volume detection to mute when the room is silent, but then the fuzz is audible as soon as someone starts talking. (Or, do you think I should ask about that separately?)

Comment: The term you're looking for is "Acoustic Echo Cancellation" (AEC).  It essentially involves applying an adaptive filter to the audio path, and updating it based on observations of the input audio.  The maths isn't exactly trivial, and requires a lot of tuning in practice.  I don't know whether there are any existing Java libraries for this, though...